# How to implement preload youtube video feature in android app?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, preloading

I am using Youtube Api for android to add play youtube videos within my app and it always buffers and play.

I was trying to find any method in the api that can allow to preload the video and then play continuously but I gone through the complete documentation but didn't found any method.

Is there any method that I missed or any workaround that could help me in implementing the same or it's against youtube's policy.

I mean the native android app too provides the same feature, why then it's not allowing for other apps ?

Comment: try to embed it with autoplay enabled, and catch the event of "started playing" or something similar. then pause instantly.

Comment: have u got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use youtubeandroidplayerapi for this.
you can refer following link for example of this.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

```
                                       or
```

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/simple-example-using-youtube-android.html

Comment: Sonu I think you should read the question again. I am already using the api you provided in the answer. I don't have any problem with playing videos. It's playing perfectly but what I wanted is that to preload the video before it starts playing so that it should never buffer in between like few years back we had this thing.